# Как включать сишные библиотки в cmake vs2022

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022

Если я делаю проект без cmake то я могу включать, например, stdlib.h(который лежит в windows kits), но с cmake ide видит только cstdlib (который лежит в include компилятора), причем который не работает потому-что внутри себя включает stdlib.h. Я скачал все sdk которые только можно и пытался добавлять `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0)`, но это ничего не дало. Как мне заставить это работать???

использую vs2022

Comment: Пригодился бы [mcve].